# Tricycle kinematics

Tags: kinematics

[image]

I am learning Robotics. I came across the following equations for tricycle kinematics. I don't understand why the velocity along the $y$-axis is $0$ in the robot reference frame. Shouldn't it be $V_s\sin\alpha$? Or else, the robot will not turn right?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $y$-axis in the tricycle's reference frame is parallel to the rear axle of the tricycle. The two wheels on that axle impose a constraint on the tricycle's motion when that motion has been constrained to *no slippage* (as specified in the lower left bubble in your graphic where it states `we assume no slippage` for the expression $V_y(t)=0$). Because the back wheels are presumably perpendicular to their axle (the tricycle's $y$-axis), they will prevent all motion parallel to this axle unless the wheels are allowed to *slide* sideways. Remember that wheels cannot *roll* sideways, they can only roll *perpendicular* to their axle!

Edit:

It would help immensely if you would provide a definition of *all* variables in your problem and clearly identify them in any diagrams provided. For example, you speak of a velocity along the $y$-axis, but the $y$-axis was *not* marked on your original diagram, but was on the second diagram, that helps a lot. Your diagrams show a $X_b,\, Y_b$ coordinate system which presumably is the stationary reference frame used to describe the motion of the tricycle, but you haven't given it a name! In my mind's eye, I visualize the tricycle moving about on some *floor*, and would describe that reference frame using the subscript $f$ instead of $b$ as in  $X_f,\, Y_f$. I cannot think of any term starting with a $b$ that comes close to the concept of a *floor*! Hence I will refer to your  $X_b,\, Y_b$ frame as *the floor reference frame*.

Now on to your question regarding the resolution of $V_s$ in the *tricyle reference frame*. First, $V_s$ is not a *velocity* (because it's not a *vector* and velocity *is* a vector) but is a *speed* (a *scalar* quantity) and is the *magnitude* of a velocity vector. What is $V_s$ the *speed* of?

> $V_s$ is the **speed** of the *point of contact* of the front wheel with the
>   floor in the floor's frame of reference.

Another way to think about $V_s$:

> $V_s$ is what an speedometer connected to the front wheel would read.

Think about what the speedometer reading in your car tells you about how your car is moving parallel to its rear axle.

The speed of that point of contact in the tricycle's frame of reference will *always* be zero if we assume that the steering axis for the front wheel is perpendicular to the floor. According to your diagram, we must assume this to be the case as no other geometry for the steering is shown. Think of it this way: when the tricycle is not moving, your can change the orientation of the front wheel to anything you like without changing the location *on the floor* where that wheel makes contact with the floor. Note also that the location of that point of contact in the *tricycle's* frame does not change either. In the tricycle's frame that point is precisely the location of the center of the steering axle which, by your graphic, is located the distance $d$ along the tricycle's $x$-axis and was *fixed* when the tricycle was constructed. The key point here is that the speed of the steering axle *in the tricycle frame of reference* must always be zero independent of the motion of the tricycle in the *floor frame of reference*. Since the velocity of the steering axis *in the tricycle frame* is always zero, its component along any tricycle coordinate axis will also always be zero. Specifically, its component along the tricycle's $y$ axis will be zero, not $V_s \sin\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

of course, different points of the tricycle will have different speeds.

Taking the tricycle reference system centered at mid of rear axis, with $y$ in the direction of the axis, then all points at $x=0$ will have $v_y=0$, since that line is going through the center of rotation. Only $v_x$ is different from zero there.

**But** the lines $0<x$ are not going through the center of rotation and there you have $v_y \ne 0$.
In particular , at the point of the steering wheel, the speed will be as you say.